# linear grammar with unequal number of 0s and 1s

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Is it possible to come up with a linear grammar with unequal number of 0s and 1s?

Such as 0100, 01100, 111,1,0, 100101001...

I know there is a context-free grammar for this, but is there a linear grammar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grammar is regular if and only if it is either left regular or right regular. The left regular grammars are equivalent to the left linear grammars. The right regular grammars are equivalent to the right linear grammars. Therefore, if a regular grammar exists that generates the indicated language, then it is either right or left regular, and hence equivalent to either a left or right linear grammar.

**edit<sub>1</sub>:**

Note that there's no regular grammar generating the indicated language *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>. To see this, consider the fact that  *L*<sub>EQ</sub> = { w : *n*<sub>a</sub>(*w*) = *n*<sub>b</sub>(*w*)} is the complement of *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>. Because the regular languages are closed under complementation and *L*<sub>EQ</sub> is *not* a regular language, *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> is *not* a regular language.

**edit<sub>2</sub>:**

I believe the pumping lemma for linear languages can be used to show that the indicated language *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> is not linear. Here is what I've come up with. I'm fairly confident it's correct. My primary concern is that you were *asked* - presumably - for a linear language generating the indicated language; however, I came to the conclusion that there is no such grammar.

Assume *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> is linear. By the pumping lemma for linear languages, there exists an *n* > 0 depending on *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> such that for all *z* ∈ *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>, *z* can be written *uvwxy* where:

- |*vx*| > 0,
- |*uvxy*| ≤ *n*, and
- *uv*<sup>i</sup>*wx*<sup>i</sup>*y* ∈ *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> for all *i* ≥ 0.

Let *n* be the constant guaranteed be the pumping lemma. Consider the string

- *z* = *a*<sup>n</sup>*b*<sup>(n! + 2n)</sup>*a*<sup>n</sup>

Since *z* ∈ *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>, it can be decomposed into substrings *uvwxy* satisfying the constraints of the pumping lemma such that, for all *i* ≥ 0, the string

- *uv*<sup>i</sup>*wx*<sup>i</sup>*y* = *a*<sup>|u|</sup>*a*<sup>i|v|</sup>*a*<sup>(n - |u| - |v|)</sup>*b*<sup>(n! + 2n)</sup>*a*<sup>(n - |x| - |y|)</sup>*a*<sup>i|x|</sup>*a*<sup>|y|</sup>

is a member of *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>. Since 1 ≤ |*vx*| ≤ n, |*vx*| divides *n*!. Hence, (*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1) is a natural number. Setting *i* to (*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1) gives the string

- *z*' = *uv*<sup>(*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1)</sup>*wx*<sup>(*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1)</sup>*y* = *a*<sup>|u|</sup>*a*<sup>(*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1)|v|</sup>*a*<sup>(n - |u| - |v|)</sup>*b*<sup>(n! + 2n)</sup>*a*<sup>(n - |x| - |y|)</sup>*a*<sup>(*n*!|*vx*|<sup>-1</sup> + 1)|x|</sup>*a*<sup>|y|</sup>

Simplifying the pumped string gives us an equal number of *a*'s and *b*'s:

- *n*<sub>a</sub>(*z*') = 2n - |*vx*| + (*n*!|vx|<sup>-1</sup> + 1)|*vx*| = 2n + *n*!

Since (2n + *n*!) is equivalent to the number of *b*'s in the pumped string, *z*' ∉ *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub>. But this contradicts the assumption that *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> is a linear language. Hence, *L*<sub>UNEQ</sub> is not a linear language.

Comment: yes sorry i updated my question. I meant i know there is a CFG for this, but i can't seem figure out if there is something linear to solve this problem.

Comment: I updated the post with an ostensible proof that the language containing an unequal number of *a*'s and *b*'s isn't linear. If you see any problems, please let me know.

Comment: Edit, again. Can I ask what textbook you're using? I just looked through a few formal languages books I had lying around to see whether the author expected the reader to find a grammar, or determine if one exists.

Comment: sipser mostly, just reading other online lectures as well. Haven't got to the proofs yet, but i just couldn't find a linear grammar that existed for this situation. Nice answer though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I have never read Sipser's book. I'll have to look it up, because most introduction to formal languages books don't present the pumping lemma for linear languages. Sounds good.